# best prcatice how to map snmp trap to kafka message

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, snmp

I am having some trouble in finding a method or algorithm on how to map a snmp trap to a kafka message.
My idea is simple to have a microservice that will catch the trap message and will convert it by using an avro serialization contract, and send to kafka topic.

I want to make a generic microservice that can catch different versions of snmp traps (different device software versions), and send to same kafka topic, is this even possible? Or I need to have an handler per each snmp trap version.

Comment: I doubt anything is impossible, but you won't find existing methods or algorithms for everything. There is no "generic" solution as far as I know, but you just need very simple code to implement your own.

Comment: Hi Lex, there is a generic solution, https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-snmp but this is not really what i need..